# Patterns in Binary Fractions with Python

Tags: python, binary, numbers

Researching **pattern identification** requires to identify the repeating patterns in **binary** representations of **fractions** of rational numbers.  `bin(2**24/n)` **strips the leading zeros**, e.g. `bin(2**24/11)` -> `0b101110100010111010001` instead of `0b000101110100010111010001`. The number of leading zeros is variable of course. The obvious pattern here is 0001011101...

I am a nubee with Python still on the learning curve. Is there a Python-appropriate way to approach this?

Comment: Huh? `bin(2**24/3)` is 0b10101010101010101010101 on Python 2.x and error on Python 3.x

Comment: Does your solution need to be in Python? If not, I can recommend several other ways to do it. BTW, 2^24/3 = 10101010101010101010101.(01), where (01) means the 01 repeats forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find the [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) module useful if you have more advanced needs than string formatting can provide.

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> a = BitArray(24)          # 24 zero bits
>>> a.uint = 2**24/11         # set the unsigned integer propery
>>> a.bin                     # get the binary propery
'000101110100010111010001'
```

It will never cut off leading zero bits, and can do a few other useful tricks

```
>>> a.uint /= 2
>>> a.bin
'000010111010001011101000'
>>> list(a.findall('0b1011'))
[4, 14]
>>> a *= 2     # concatenation
>>> a.bin
'000010111010001011101000000010111010001011101000'
>>> a.replace('0b00001', '0xe')
2              # 2 replacements made
>>> a.bin
'1110011101000101110100011100111010001011101000'
```

I'm not sure of what your exact needs are, so all this could be overkill and you might not want to use an external library in any case, but Python in-built support for bit arrays is a little basic.

Comment: This looks dead-on. My approach was more simplistic but not as versatile.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with string formatting, in 2.6+:

```
>>> '{0:024b}'.format(23)
'000000000000000000010111'
```